# Beginners Java Array Question

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to output a square of X's using an array. The diagonals of the square will be filled with 'X' and the empties will be filled with spaces '_'.

Here's the code I got:

```
public static char[][] square(int z) {
    int size=5;
    char[][] myArr = new char[size][size];
    for (int c=0;c<size;c++)
        myArr[c][c]='X';
    for (int r=0;r<size;r++)
    {
        for (int col=size-1;col>=0;col--)//put X
        {
            myArr[r][col]='X';
        }
    }
    for(int count=0;count<size;count++){
        if (myArr[count][count]!='X')
            myArr[count][count]=' ';
    }

    return myArr;

}
```

This should be working-I ran it manually on paper and everything should have been fine. What can the problem be?

Comment: if everything should have been fine, what wasn't fine?  as in, what error message did you get?

Comment: looking at the code it could be a few things :)

Comment: Not really related to the problem you ask (as I think eumiro posted the correct solution), but I'm just curious, are you actually using the parameter "int z" in the function at all?

Comment: Mind telling me what isn't working or better what exactly you're expecting?

Comment: Expected: X---X (where - is a space)
Actual:   XXXXX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code seems a little bit overcomplicated with all those ifs and clever loops.
Just fill array with 'background chars' and then draw diagonal.

```
    char[][] myArr = new char[size][size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        Arrays.fill(myArr[i], ' ');
    }
    // now we have square filled with spaces

    // draw diagonal, like you did it
    for (int c = 0; c < size; c++) {
        myArr[c][c] = 'X';
        myArr[c][size - c - 1] = 'X';
    }
```

**edit**
Updated to draw two diagonals.

Comment: I dont see what you did there..myArr[i]=new char[size]..what was that for? Also when you use Arrays.fill(myArr[i], ' '), how come you only specify one dimension and not two?

Comment: @Nikita Rybak: The code you posted still only draws one diagonal (from NW corner to SE corner). You still need to draw a diagonal from NE to SW corners. Also, why initialize the array values with "background chars"? Besides adding overhead, I can't think of anything else it would do.

Comment: @SauceMaster _The code you posted still only draws one diagonal (from NW corner to SE corner)_ I mentioned it and said why in my answer.

Comment: I thought I was drawing two? Theres the first loop where the dimensions are the same [c][c], which is the left to right loop. Then there is the other nested loop which draws the right to left loop, no?

Comment: @SauceMaster _Besides adding overhead_ Are you saying it's a waste of resources to make _N^2 + 2*N_ assignments instead of _N^2_? :) I just did what produces simpler code.

Comment: @Nikita Rybak: I think I misinterpreted the role your code was intended to fill; i.e. obviate the step of adding the spaces (' '). Apologies for my careless once-over.

Comment: @newtojava two-dimensional array in java is just array of arrays. No magic. So, if you have 'char[][] myArr', then 'myArr[0]' has type 'char[]'. And 'Arrays.fill' takes 'char[]'.

Comment: @newtojava Your first loop draws perfectly correct diagonal. Nothing nested. So, why do we need nested loop to draw another diagonal? The fact that two loops (inner*outer) will draw _size^2_ (25 in your case) X's is already suspicious: diagonal has only _size_ (5) X's.

Comment: @Nikita so if we take the first dimension to represent the rows in the square, are we just using the code you had to fill every row with spaces?

Comment: @newtojava exactly, row by row. Or you could use inner loop with the same effect, something like _for(int col=0; col < size; ++col) {myArr[row][col] = 'X'}_. Sorry for confusion :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is probably, that here:

```
for (int r=0;r<size;r++)
{
    for (int col=size-1;col>=0;col--)//put X
    {
        myArr[r][col]='X';
    }
}
```

you are itering over the whole square (size * size) and not just drawing the Northeast - Southwest diagonal.

Try to replace it with this:

```
for (int r=0;r<size;r++)
{
    myArr[r][size - r] = 'X'
}
```

**EDIT**: To make your code little bit compacter:

```
public static char[][] square(int size) {
    char[][] myArr = new char[size][size];
    for (int c = 0; c < size; c++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
            if ((c == r) || ( c == size - r)) {
                myArr[r][c] = 'X';
            } else { 
                myArr[r][c] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    return myArr;
}
```

Comment: This still only covers one diagonal- the easy one where the rows and columns numbers are equal. What about the right to left diagonal where the row and column numbers are not the same?

Comment: Isn't ((c == r) || ( c == size - r)) covering both diagonals?

Answer (score 1):

When you Iterate your loop, you want the diagonals to be 'x'. You can save a lot of work and code by minimizing how much you iterate.

```
public static char[][] square(int z) {
int size = z;
char[][] myArr = new char[size][size];

for(int i = 0;i < size;i++)
{
    for(int j = 0;j < size;j++)
    {
        if(i == j)
        {
             myArr[i][j] = 'X';
        }
        else if(i + j == size - 1)
        {
             myArr[i][j] = 'X';
        else
        {
             myArr[i][j] = " ";
        }
     }
}

return myArr;

}
```

Comment: This is only the right to left diagonal, what about the left to right diagonal, where i!=j?

Comment: Also, your not even using the parameter 'z'. We could eliminate that as well.  I'm not quite sure what your challenging us on, but I think that function just creates the array you described, if we want to be creative we could just use x as the dimensions of the square and have an x,x sized square with 'X' in the middle! =)

Comment: I had it, but you still gota subtract   i + j = size - 1;

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that when you do `new char[size][size];` you still should `new` each `char` array before you use it.

This can be merged with the first `for` loop easily:

```
 for (int c=0;c<size;c++) {
    myArr[c] = new char[size]; // allocate the array
    myArr[c][c]='X';
 }
```

Next the algorithm doesn't work, though this one would:

```
public static char[][] square (int z) {
    int size = z, cap=((size+1) /2);
    char[][] myArr = new char[size][size];
    for (int c = 0; c < cap; c++) { // iterate only half the array doing 4 positions per iteration
        myArr[c] = new char[size];
        myArr[size-c-1] = new char[size];
        Arrays.fill(myArr[size-c-1],' '); // make the new line blank
        Arrays.fill(myArr[c], ' '); // make the new line blank
        myArr[c][c] = 'X';  // top left to center
        myArr[size - c - 1][size-c-1] = 'X'; // bottom right to center
        myArr[size - c - 1][c] = 'X'; // bottom left to center
        myArr[c][size - c - 1] = 'X'; // top right to center
    }
    return myArr;
}

/** test square algorithm by printing it to System.out */
private static void testSquare () {
    char[][] sq = square(5);
    for (char[] l : sq) {
        System.out.println(new String(l));
    }
}
```