# Java Array Question

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a triangle where empty cells have spaces and non empty cells have X's.

```
public static char[][] Triangle(int size) {
    char[][] triangle = new char[size][size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Arrays.fill(triangle[i], '_');
    }

    for (int rows = 0; rows < size; rows++) {
        for (int columns = 0; columns < rows + 1; columns++) {
            triangle[rows][columns] = 'T';

        }
    }

    return triangle;
}
```

Somethings not working though. Not sure what it is?
Edit: I found a fix and made the changes above.

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the expected behavior? What did you get instead? Did you get a compiler error, or a runtime error? How are you calling `Triangle()`?

Comment: Duplicate and homework tag is missing

Comment: @silico just the output was wrong. For first row, it was supposed to be just X with spaces, but instead I got XXXXX (using 5 as size)

Comment: @fprime: That should've been part of your question. You should edit your question to include exactly what output you're expecting for a given `size`, then include exactly what output you actually got. If you don't include that vital piece of information, you'll get many shotgun answers that may or may not solve your problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799543/beginners-java-array-question

Comment: @fprime - is the other question yours as well, or of your classmate :) ?

Comment: @mhaller And how do you know this is homework?

Comment: i thought it was a duplicate to the one i linked, since both used "_" und "X" and it was about two-dimensional char arrays. I overlooked the triangular vs. square (although that's still very similar). Sorry if i'm wrong. 'Homework' tag should be used so answers do not just give solution, but a hint on how to solve the problem on your own, which is better for understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an if-clause within the 2nd loop. For example

```
if (rows == columns)
```

will put X on the main diagonal. I don't know what's your exact condition, but add it there.

(Also, use curly brackets, especially with nested constructs - it makes it more readable and less error-prone)

Comment: I dont get how this will help? What does this if do?

Comment: currently you are putting `x` everywhere. Adding an if will limit the X-es to the positions you want.

Comment: Ok I did that, but now that only puts an X where the rows and columns are equal. That should be the stopping point, but what about all the cells before? For example on the 3rd row, if there are five cells total, then I only have an X in the middle. What about the first 2 cells? How can I fix this?

Comment: Ok I tweaked around a bit and found the fix: for(int rows=0;rows<size;rows++){
        for(int columns=0;columns<rows+1;columns++)
        {
            triangle[rows][columns]='T';

        }
I still dont understand how this loop works though. I run it on paper but I'm only getting diagonal output, not triangular.

Comment: @fprime - where in the question did you specify you want trianglular X-es? And Where do you suppose to have them - show what output you expect and don't make us assume.